# How to set the Telegram bot to automatically click button

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I try to change some code lines of a URL Uploader Bot.

This is the Original Repo.
https://github.com/prgofficial/URLuploader-With-Hotstar

When user send a URL for this bot it Reply with a Msg So user have to Choose one option form Inline Keyboard Button.

So what I want to do is change bot to click on first button automatically if user never respond before 10 seconds. ([Here is a Screen shot of that Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWsd.jpg). I need to click Automatically on "S mp4" Button)

Here the links of some code line...

- [Code that says to reply after user send a link to this bot.](https://github.com/prgofficial/URLuploader-With-Hotstar/blob/master/plugins/youtube_dl_echo.py#L265)
- [Code line that create the Inline Keyboard Button](https://github.com/prgofficial/URLuploader-With-Hotstar/blob/master/plugins/youtube_dl_echo.py#L156)

Please Help me to change this bot.

Comment: Buttons are handled by functions, so you can simply use cron job to call this function in 10 seconds, if user responds you should cancel cron job.